# NODE_ENV gulp, как задать через консоль переменную

Tags: windows, node.js, gulp

Добрый день, пытаюсь разделить gulp.task на production и development. Делаю это через gulp-if, проверка наличие переменной. Но планирую сделать возможным задание этой переменной через консоль, с последующим запуском gulp.

Запускаю командой: `NODE_ENV=production gulp scss`

Код который есть не работает. Выдает ошибку:

```
..\gulp-front-end>NODE_ENV
"NODE_ENV" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

вот код из gulp

```
const gulpIf = require('gulp-if');

const isDevelopment = !process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development';



gulp.task('scss', function() {
    return gulp
        .src('source/scss/style.scss')
        .pipe(plumber(
            errorHandler
        ))
        .pipe(scss.sync())
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions'],
            cascade: false
        }))
        .pipe(gulpIf(isDevelopment, cssnano()))
        .pipe(gulpIf(isDevelopment, rename({suffix: '.min'})))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/css'));
});
```

Comment: У вас же windows?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9249830

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Windows для задания переменных окружения используется команда [`set`](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/set.mspx?mfr=true). В вашем случае, для запуска Gulp в *production* окружении вам следует использовать вот такой однострочник:

```
set NODE_ENV="production" && gulp scss
```

Comment: Немного дополню: `set NODE_ENV=production` - устанавливаете переменную, жмете enter, затем `gulp scss` всегда будет собирать продакшн версию, для сборки девелоперской версии необходимо вновь установить переменную `set NODE_ENV=development`

Comment: Держать в голове текущее состояние переменной `NODE_ENV` - пустая трата сил. Именно поэтому я и указал в ответе на использование операции `&&` для установки переменной окружения **и** запуска сборки.

Comment: ну так все остальные запуски будут делаться именно с этим значением, пока снова ее не поменяешь....

Comment: "_Явное лучше, чем неявное._" ;)